# split array to sub array by step in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

In Python i can slice array with "jump-step". Example:

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 

In [4]: a[1:7:2] # start from index = 1 to index < 7, with step = 2
Out[4]: [2, 4, 6]
```

Can Ruby do it?

Comment: Short answer: Not with a shorthand notation no.

Comment: Your example is not good as it is not clear whether you want to skip the values or by the indices (probably the latter).

Comment: If it was a for loop in any other language he wants the `i++` to be `i+2` for every iteration in this case.

Comment: Your output seems to be wrong. If you start from index = 1 to index = 7, with step = 2, then you should get [2, 4, 6, 8].

Comment: @sawa i'm sorry, i'm a beginer in python too. To index < 7. I run in ipython.

Comment: @sawa - Tried it in Python. Apparently that's how it works.

Comment: @seph I meant the compatibility between the description and the expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a.values_at(*(1...7).step(2)) - [nil]
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Although in the above case the `- [nil]` part is not necessary, it serves just in case your range exceeds the size of the array, otherwise you may get something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a.values_at(*(1..23).step(2))
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: +1, this is the one. I wrote an answer with `values_at(*(1...7).step(2))` and then I saw yours :-) Maybe it's better `1...7` to use 7 (the number the OP mentions) instead of 6.

Comment: @tokland thanks for your comment,I just updated as your comment.

Comment: @J3STER Don't edit the answer. Rather use comments box to tell the author how he can improve this.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby, to get the same output:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
(1...7).step(2).map { |i| a[i] }
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really miss the Python slice steps syntax you can get Ruby to do something very similar.

```
class Array
  alias_method :brackets, :[]

  def [](*args)
    return brackets(*args) if args.length != 3
    start, stop, step = *args
    self.values_at(*(start...stop).step(step))
  end
end

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr[1,7,2]
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Python allows omitting any of the args, `a[2::3]` for example.